# VS 2019: how to disable warning 'Please install the 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild' NuGet package to enable TypeScript compilation in your project.'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

How to disable warning 'Please install the 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild' NuGet package to enable TypeScript compilation in your project.'?

I do not need TS compilation with MSBuild - I do it with custom tools (building `webpack` bundle, manaually or with devserver).

[image]

After changing build action to "Content" warning still exists (details: was "none", this is the only one ts file in the project, solution restart doesn't help; but there are other TS files in other projects and may be they "hooked" somehow the MSBuild warning for all projects with ts files)

[image]

Comment: Hi Roman,any update about this issue?

Comment: Thank you, very much! My question was simplified. Actually I do not use the "npm run typescript" by itself - I compile typescripts building webpack bundle - or webpack dev server do it for me.  So now I'm thinkig what does your answer mean for me. Actually I still not happy that I'm forced to put "Custom tool" to each ts file (when I do not need it). Chmm... But thank you very much for investigation.

Comment: Since you abandoned the custom tool for typescript in vs, I suggest you could just set the `Build Action` of the typescript files to `Content` or `None`, then the error will disappear. I have found that simply suppressing the warning does not eliminate this particular warning. Otherwise, you should right-click on the project properties-->`Typescript Build`--> and then set a version and the error will disappear. But this will use MSBuild.

Comment: If you just set these typescript files' `Build Action` to `Content` to eliminate the problem, do not forget to accept this answer and if my answer helps you handle this issue, please do not forget to accept it. Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Specifieng "Build Action" to content (was "none") didn't help. I will add an image.

Comment: Did your solution contain other projects and if so, did other projects also have some typescript files? You can try to unload other projects(right-click on these projects-->`unload project`). Remain the only one project and then `rebuild your project` to test again. Or you should change `build action` to `Content` for other typescript files of other  projects.

Comment: Mr Qian solution worked for me.

Comment: It looks like a fix is coming, but not yet delivered (last updated Nov 02, 2021 -- maybe fixed in VS2022?): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/permanent-warning-please-install-the-microsofttype/1555740

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this might be fixed in VS2022, but if you're still on VS2019 the following worked for me:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>4.2</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You'd manually add this to your .csproj file.  I had to close and re-open VS afterwards too, but I don't get the error anymore.  It also wanted to install TS version 4.2 but it doesn't seem to be compiling with it.  Still not a great solution, but it's probably all we've got until Microsoft fixes it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/permanent-warning-please-install-the-microsofttype/1555740

Comment: Not fixed in vs2002

Comment: I was missing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript directory, so installed typescript via "Get Tool and Features" -> individual components, search for TypeScript, install it, and set the <TypeScriptToolsVersion> value to the installed version, e.g. <TypeScriptToolsVersion>4.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>

Answer (score -1):

> VS 2019: how to disable warning 'Please install the
> 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild' NuGet package to enable TypeScript
> compilation in your project.'

You can use [NoWarn msbuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2019#to-suppress-specific-warnings-for-visual-basic) to suppress this warning.

**Solution**

Add this in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <NoWarn>xxx(the related waning code like cs0219)</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

================================

**Update 1**

Since the warning does not have a number, you cannot use `NoWarn` to suppress it.

Instead, you can use

```
<WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
```

**However**, it will suppress all the warnings in your project. For your issue, it is the best way but still has some drawbacks if you want the other warnings.

**As a suggestion**, you could create a new configuration called **Test**
(**Build**-->**Configuration Manager**-->click your project and click **New** under **Configuration** drop down box)

, then add these in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Test'">
      <WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**You** can use the **Test** Configuration to build your project and it will suppress the warning.

**If** you want to see the other warnings or handle other warnings, you can switch to **Debug** or **Release** mode to build your project.

====================

**Update 2**

After a deep research, I have reproduced your issue in my side:

[image]

**Since** you do not specify the TypeScript version in MSBuild of VS so that the error occurs.

The cause of it is that you have set the **Build Action** of the typescript files to **TypeScript file**. If you set to it, MSBuild will identify them and let MSBuild to use Type Script to build them. Since you do not use TypeScript of MSBuild, so the error happens.

**Solution**

You can set the **Build Action** of every typescript file to **Content** and add custom tool to `npm run typescript`.

[image]

**Then** restart your project to test again and I am sure that the error will go away.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing that info. To suppress the warning, you have to use `<WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>` to suppress all the warnings since it is not have a number. Besides, you can write the xml property in a new configuration called `Test` and then use the `Test` to build your project to suppress the warning and if you want to see the other warnings, you can switch to use `Debug` or `Release` mode. It is effective and still has some limitations. However, it is the best way for your issue.

Comment: After a deep research, I have found the problem. Please check my `update 2`.